# Magento 2.3.4 Plugin Sitemap not working

Tags: custom, magento2.3.4, sitemaps, after-plugin

I've had a plugin working on 2.2.2 version but it's not working on 2.3.4. Its seem that `collectSitemapItems()` method is not firing even in native magento WHen I `print_r('Die');die;`

```
public function collectSitemapItems()
    {
        print_r('Not firing');die;
        /** @var $helper \Magento\Sitemap\Helper\Data */
    ...
```

But it's printing under protected method `_initSitemapItems()`

```
/**
     * Initialize sitemap
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _initSitemapItems()
    {
     print_r('Working Here');die; 
    ...
```

My plugin have `afterCollectSitemapItems()` Method:

```
public function afterCollectSitemapItems(
        Sitemap $subject
    )
    {
        print_r('Not firing here either');die;
```

My Plugin di.xml:

```
 <type  name="Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap">
   <plugin name="vendor-sitemap" sortOrder="1"  disabled="false" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Sitemap\Plugin"/>
 </type>
```

Any ideas why this isn't working anymore?

Answer (score 3):

I've found out that my plugin is firing ok after printing in `__constructor` bu method `afterCollectSitemapItems` not any more. So using public method `generateXml` like so:

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sitemap\Helper\Data $helper
        ) {
            $this->helper = $helper;
    }
    public function beforeGenerateXml(
        \Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap $subject
        )
    {
        $storeId = $subject->getStoreId();
        $newRecords = [];
        $object = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $object->setId(['test_id']);
        $object->setUrl('test-url');
        $object->setUpdatedAt('2020-04-17 14:24:38');
        $newRecords['test_id'] = $object;
        $subject->addSitemapItem(new  \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            ['changefreq' => $this->helper->getPageChangefreq($storeId),
             'priority' => $this->helper->getPagePriority($storeId),
             'collection' => $newRecords,]
         ));
    }

}
```

Worked, Sorted!

**Note/Tip:** only `before` method works on `generateXml` and also when generating always open xml in incognito mode as is caches in chrome browser.

Comment: Thanks for that @Juliano

Answer (score 2):

Try this below and add your die as well

```
   public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sitemap\Helper\Data $helper
        ) {
            $this->helper = $helper;
    }
    public function afterCollectSitemapItems(
        \Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap $subject
        )
    {

        die('Not firing here either');
        $storeId = $subject->getStoreId();
        $newRecords = [];
        $object = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $object->setId(['test_id']);
        $object->setUrl('test-url');
        $object->setUpdatedAt('2020-04-17 14:24:38');

        $newRecords['test_id'] = $object;

        $subject->addSitemapItem(new  \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [

                'changefreq' => $this->helper->getPageChangefreq($storeId),
                'priority' => $this->helper->getPagePriority($storeId),
                'collection' => $newRecords,
            ]
         ));
    }

}
```

Comment: can I see your DI.XML file

Comment: this is exactly what I have. it seems that `CollectSitemapItems` or in my plugin `afterCollectSitemapItems` isn't doing anything. but Ive found a way around it.

Comment: @JulianoVargas the issue might be where you using the di.xml. When i did it i didnt put it inside frontend or adminhtml. I kept my di.xml in etx/di.xml

but if you got it working that's good news will you let me know how you fixed it just wanted to see what was the error with it

Comment: @JulianoVargas Facing same issue not calling afterCollectSitemapItems in plugin. can you please share your di.xml and plugin file here so get the idea how you have fixed it.